# Efficient and Optimised way to map all the resuts of a sql query in Spring Boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, groovy, java-8

I want to fetch some records from my my-sql database through java code
below is the code snippet

**Sql Query Result contains almost 200 fields and i have to set all the 200 fields in ResultMetaDataVO domain.**

What is the efficient and optimised solution of this particular scenario?

```
    String datasourceUrl = dataSourceUtil.dataSourceUrl
    String datasourceUsername = dataSourceUtil.dataSourceUserName
    String datasourcePassword = dataSourceUtil.dataSourcePassword

    Connection connection = null
    ResultSet resultSet = null
    ResultMetaDataVO resultMetaDataVO = new ResultMetaDataVO()

    try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(datasourceUrl, datasourceUsername, datasourcePassword)
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement()
        String query = "select * from order_details where uuid = ${uuid}"
        //uuid comes from method parameter
        if (query) {
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query)
            if (resultSet) {
                while (resultSet.next()) {

                     // Set every fields of result set in ResultMetaDataVO
                
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

See i will bound that query result fields to variables of ResultMetaDataVO

For Example -
`resultMetaDataVO.orderId = resultSet.getString("orderId")`

my query which return a order details it may have around 200 fields some of them i know and some of them i dont know the fields which i know i declared it as a varable in ResultMetaDataVO class But in my case the

i have list of uuid and i am iterating in that list of uuid and then i am querying the database by single uuid. I have list of uuid -> iterating over uuid -> query database of a single uuid -> set the results in ResultMetaDataVo

Comment: "What is the efficient and optimised solution of this particular scenario?" - Do you want to optimize for network traffic, processor time, memory consumption, or something else?

Comment: FYI.... You have `String query = "select * from order_details where uuid = ${uuid}"` followed by `if(query) { ... }`.  That `if` clause is *always* going to be `true`.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown i about that if condition this is just a code snippet i will do refracotring in my code befor pushing it 
Look i want to know that is there is any better approach, my approach is setting the fields in ResultMetaDataVO class 
But my query will contains more than 100 fields

Comment: proecessor time

Comment: "my approach is setting the fields in ResultMetaDataVO class" - It looks like you are creating 1 instance of `ResultMetaDataVO` and then later iterating over query results.  Is it the case that all of the query results will be bound to properties that are in `ResultMetaDataVO` or in classes that properties in `ResultMetaDataVO` point to?

Comment: Seeing the source code for `ResultMetaDataVO` and `ResultMetaDataDomain` will help.

Comment: See i will bound that query result fields to variables of ResultMetaDataVO 

For Example - resultMetaDataVO.orderId = resultSet.getString("orderId") - my query which return a order details it may have around 200 fields some of them i know and some of them i dont know the fields which i know i declared it as a varable in ResultMetaDataVO class

But in my case the i have list of uuid and i am iterating in that list of uuid and then i am querying the database by single uuid.

I have list of uuid -> iterating over uuid -> query database of a single uuid -> set the results in ResultMetaDataVo

Comment: @JeffScottBrown

Comment: Can you please share the code of ResultMetaDataVO  and ResultMetaDataDomain that you've mentioned in the comment - what is the connection between these classes?

Comment: @MarkBramnik Its a typo both the class are same